# Problem Saving Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My code is:

```
NSLog(@"saving jpeg");
NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpeg",docDir, [self.Youtubearray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([Result1 backgroundImage], 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
[data2 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Basically Result1 is a UIButton and i download the image of the button before in the code and set the background image as the downloaded image. Is there a way to save this image from the button or will i have to download it again ?

Thanks

Mason

Comment: What doesn't work, getting the image, getting its bytes in NSData or saving it to a file?

Comment: [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([Result1 backgroundImage], 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality

Comment: use directly as NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([Result1 backgroundImage], 1.0f)

Comment: additional to my answer: you should use the currentImage oder currentBackgroundImage property to get the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([Result1 backgroundImage], 1.0f);
```

If the **Result1** cannot obtain the jpeg image data, it will return nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *img; // your image
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.9f);
```

I'm saving using:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:data attributes:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the idea of saving a downloaded image into a button doesn't sound very good. You should consider keeping the image somewhere in model/controller part of MVC. A view is not a particularly good place to keep any data because if the view goes away, the data is released too.

Secondly, `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` returns an NSData object, so `[NSData dataWithData: jpegData]` is unnecessary.

Thirdly, I think `[Result1 backgroundImage]` returns either nil or something like UIStretchableImage. You should check the value returned.

Comment: You are wrong. I totally don't know *why*, but without `dataWithData:`, that doesn't work — even though it's already a `NSData`. Anyone can explain?!